# Помогите разобраться с AJAX и стандартными действиями браузера

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Есть следующая конструкция:

```
<nav>
    <a href="index/">Главная</a>
    <a href="docs/">Документы</a>
    <a href="about/">О Нас</a>
    <a href="contacts/">Контакты</a>
</nav>
```

Нажатие на ссылку обрабатывается следующим образом:

```
$('nav a').click(function(){

    var hr = 'href=' + $(this).attr('href').slice(0, -1); // читаем href у ссылки
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: hr, 
        success: function(response) {
             if (response == 'noaction') return true;
             $('body').prepend(response);
             return false;
            },
        error: function(response) {
             return true;
            }
        });
    return false; // нужно ли оно тут?
})
```

Смысл в следующем:
 - если AJAX даёт ошибку или ответ (response) == 'noaction' тогда браузер должен "стандартно" перейти по ссылке на которую кликнули.
 - если AJAX даёт любой response отличный от 'noaction' то вставить его в body и НЕ ПЕРЕХОДИТЬ по ссылке.

У меня же браузер никогда не переходит, помогите разобраться!(jQuery подгружено, ajax сервер выдаёт верные результаты), не могу расставить верно return'ы :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('nav a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    var hr = 'href=' + href.slice(0, -1); // читаем href у ссылки
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: hr, 
        success: function(response) {
             if (response == 'noaction') {
               window.location = href;
             }
             else {
               $('body').prepend(response);
             }
            },
        error: function(response) {
             window.location = href;
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: Равнодушный, спасибо вам огромное!